# How to apply Required attribute on Composite Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a Composite type for a field in model.

I have a field in my model named PersonDetails

```
public Phone PhoneDetails{get;set;}
```

Phone is another model containing three other fields as

```
int MobilePhone;
int WorkPhone;
int HomePhone;
```

PersonDetails is a model which I am passing to add popup.
PersonDetails has following field :

```
public String Name{get;set;}
public Phone PhoneDetails{get;set;} 
public string Address{get;set;}
```

I can apply `Required` Field attribute to remaining fields, but I want to
apply `Required` attribute to `PhoneDetails` field. The condition is that at least one of the three i.e. MobilePhone,WorkPhone or HomePhone should have a value.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: no, you cannot apply `required` annotation to complex objects. That is, you can but it validation won't apply. You can apply `required` annotation to each propery...

Comment: @DaveA : Is there any approach that will work for this siatuation.

Comment: @DaveA : The required field validation message should be fired if all the three fields are empty. I have tried to solve this issue by using Custom validation also but didn't succeded. Can you please guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to implement IValidatableObject:

```
public class PersonDetails : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Phone PhoneDetails { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (PhoneDetails.MobilePhone == 0 && PhoneDetails.WorkPhone == 0 && PhoneDetails.HomePhone == 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter at least 1 phone number", new[] { "PhoneDetails" });
    }
}
```

Your form will then show "Please enter at least 1 phone number" if none are entered.

Comment: I applied above changes but it has one problem. It gives a run time error showing "Add the refference ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" to all the places where the PhoneDetails model is used in other projects.

Comment: Yes - you will need to reference ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as I believe the interface is in that library. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of validation I always use FluentValidation.

It allows for far more complex validation scenarios than attributes / annotations and is very compatible with MVC (and all .NET code in general)

Use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.MVC4/) to add it to your project - plenty of examples and documentation are available.